# What is indexing? Why don't we use hashing for everything?

Tags: indexing, data-structures, hashmap

Going over some interview info about data structures etc.

So, as I understand, arrays are O(1) for indexing, which I believe means finding the specific element contained at space x in the array. Just want to confirm this as I am second guessing myself.

Also, hash maps are O(1) for indexing, searching, insertion and deletion. Does that not kind of make any data structure question pointless, since a hash map will always be the best solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can't do range queries with hashmaps (efficiently)

Comment: Because slooooooooow. Hint: what are the steps required to index into an array; and those required to find an item in a hashtable? (Note, I'm only answering the question as to why we use arrays at all rather than hashtables for everything. This doesn't even touch on the near infinite other use cases where one - or both - are entirely unsuitable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well indexing is not only about arrays,

according to [this](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/44896/indexing) - indexing is creating tables (indexes) that point to the location of folders, files and records. Depending on the purpose, indexing identifies the location of resources based on file names, key data fields in a database record, text within a file or unique attributes in a graphics or video file.

For your second question hash maps are not absolute or best data structures for various reasons, mainly:

- Collisions
- Hash function calculation time
- Extra memory used

Also there's lots of Data Structure questions where hashmaps are not superior:

- Data structure for finding k-th minimum element and supporting updates (Hashmap would be like bruteforce because it does not keep elements sorted, so we need something like Balanced binary search tree)
- Data structure for finding if word is in dictionary (Sure hashmap works but Trie is so much faster & less memory)
- Data structure for finding minimum element in any range of an array with updates (Once again hashmap is just too slow for this, we need something like segment tree)
- ...